# Sending a file to the server

Tags: angular

My problem is that the file needs to be wrapped in an object.
But as soon as I do it - it is empty.

**What i tryed:**

*ts:*

```
public sendFile(id: string, file: File) {
  const params = new FormData();

  params.append('file', file);  -----> Need to wrap in the invoice: {file: file}
  params.append('id', lead_id)

  return this.http.post(`url`, params)
}
```

*component:*

```
public onSubmit() {
  const { file } = this.form.value;

  this.service.sendFile(id, file).subscribe();
}
```

*What the server expects*

```
{ id: integer, invoice: { file: file } }
```

**upd1: (What else tried)**

```
public sendInvoiceFile(lead_id: number, file: File) {
  return this.http.post(`url`, {
  lead_id: lead_id,
  invoice: {
    file: file
  }
})
```

}

console: `invoice: {file: {}}`

Comment: `id` is undefined in `onSubmit`, `id` is `string` in `sendFile()` and `id` is `integer` in "what the server expects". What errors do you get in the console, what debugging did you do to track down where the data goes null?